# read remote excel file stored on a server with authenticaion

Tags: java, excel, inputstream, xlsx

I need to access a remote excel file [https://wim-example.com/rest/api/2/issue/SDLCDEVOPS-3238/abc.xlsx](https://example.com/rest/api/2/issue/SDLCDEVOPS-3238)
that is attached to a JIRA ticket. Each time I access JIRA ticket I have to add authentication token to the connection. I have to use the XSSFWorkbook that takes inputstream

`URLConnection con1 = url1.openConnection();
 con1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic dTU3NjI3MjpGcmVtb250MTIz");`

How can I get the input stream that I can give to XSSFWorkbook?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to provide the inputstream:

Connection.**getInputStream()**

```
URLConnection con1 = url1.openConnection();
con1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic dTU3NjI3MjpGcmVtb250MTIz");

XSSFWorkbook fs = new XSSFWorkbook(con1.getInputStream());
```